TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loginWith') at AmplifyClass.notifyOAuthListener
I try to setup Amplify to my react/next project, to setup an auth with aws-cognito, i'm using typescript.
I have this error :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loginWith')
at AmplifyClass.notifyOAuthListener


_app.tsx :
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

aws-exports
const awsconfig = {
    Auth: {
        region: 'AWS_REGION',
        userPoolId: 'USER_POOL_ID',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID',
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    }
};

export default awsconfig;
version:

react : 18.3.1
next : 13.5.7
@aws-amplify/ui-react : 6.5.0
aws-amplify : 6.6.2

I don't understand why i have this error, i think i have set the corrects ids. have you any suggestions ? thx

Hello, it happens to me also... Did you find a solution?
"react": "^18.3.1",
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^6.5.5",
"aws-amplify": "^6.8.0",
